# Sql store words and their translation and their category

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I build a database (sql-server).
I have a table "words" (wordId,word,translation)
every word has to be associated with at least one category.
I have an additional table "categories" (categoryId,categoryName)
what is the best way to associate each word with all the categories it belongs?

one option:
an additional table "wordsCategories"  (wordId,categoryId)

second option:
To add a colomn in the words table
that will store all the categories ids that the word belongs, the categories ids will be seperated by a comma.
table "words" (wordId,word,translation,categories)
insert into words (wordId,word,translation,categories) values (7,"word","travail","9,12,23")

I am open to hear of a better option.

Comment: where would be the translation of each language?

Comment: `category table.... words table (wordid, word, langid) ... language table ... translation table (categoryid, wordid,transwordid)` where transwordid will come from the `words table`  this will make more sense

Answer (score 1):

my database design should be

```
--category table
categoryid
categoryname

--language table
langid
languagename

--words table
wordid
word
langid


--translation table
id
categoryid
wordid
transwordid --- from words table but the translation of the word
```

Comment: And if a word belongs to 5 categories, would it have 5 rows in the translation table? (5 times its transwordId will be written)

Comment: won't matter they are just integers unless if you want to have the words table where 1 word can be in 100 categories including the translation

Comment: If I use a few languages at the same column, won't there be collations problem. (each colomn can have it's own collation, but not each row)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely do not store the comma list!  Create a new table linking word/category IDs.  Also, make sure there is a unique constraint on both columns to keep the data nice & clean.

(As an aside, I think you will find this problem more complicated than you think as many words have same spelling/different meanings etc.)

Comment: if a word has more then one translation, I thought to store in the translation colomn a list of options seperated by coma, because the wordId is also the word file name (without the .mp3)

Comment: Never store a list in a column.  Always use a new table with one row per thing in the list.  Sounds like you need a wordID/Word table, WordID/WordID translation table as well as the ones we've covered.

Comment: It seems I am the one who lost in space. Do you think like maSTAShuFu that all the words in all languages has to be in the words table each in a row?

Comment: Yes that design is pretty much what I'd do.  Not sure if the category depends on the word in each language or as they have it.  As I mentioned, I think there are additional problems with synonyms and such, but you can make a start along these lines.